# setClientInfo is not cleared after the JDBC connection is closed

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

I am using Apache DBCP BasicDataSource pkg for dataSource

The setClientInfo is not reset after the connection close.
We are passing the properties to setClientinfo(). I wanted to reset the  properties value to null. I am trying to clear the value using the mething
*conn.getClientInfo().clear()* close the connection.

I tried using the method

```
 finally{
      if (conn !=null){
          **conn.getClientInfo().clear();**
          conn.close();
      }
    }
```

But this is not working, The clinetInfo is not getting cleared.

```
finally{
  if (conn !=null){
      **conn.getClientInfo().clear();**
      conn.close();
  }
}
```

Need to reset the ClientInfo for each connection closed. When a new connection is started we will set new value.

Comment: It is not clear what conn do you use and what conn.getClientInfo().clear() do.
And anyway, maybe you should do `conn.setClientInfo(null);`

Comment: It throws NPE . So we cannot set null

Comment: Could you, please, provide what do `setClientInfo(); getClientInfo(); clear()` ?